# ajax infinity scroll error some time same result retuen

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i am new to coding and i am writing project for teach me self about PHP social site. In post loading ajax call page number are not updating in start of recall and sometime same result are show again and again. my be add some delay in js script? please help me. Thanks

first part is post class which load post from database and second part is js script.

i check the code again all are fine but i need to delay or reduce ajax call. load is still process and ajax is trigger another call that why it have same page is load again and again.

may be delay in js script require to slow down loading process
script

```
<script>
    var userLoggedIn = '<?php echo $userLoggedIn; ?>';

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#loading').show();

        //Original ajax request for loading first posts 
        $.ajax({
            url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "page=1&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
            cache: false,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#loading').hide();
                $('.posts_area').html(data);
            }
        });


        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var height = $('.posts_area').height(); //Div containing posts
            var scroll_top = $(this).scrollTop();
            var page = $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage').val();
            var noMorePosts = $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts').val();

            if ((document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) ||
                noMorePosts == 'false') {
                $('#loading').show();
                //alert("hello");

                var ajaxReq = $.ajax({
                    url: "includes/handlers/ajax_load_posts.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "page=" + page + "&userLoggedIn=" + userLoggedIn,
                    cache: false,

                    success: function(response) {
                        $('.posts_area').find('.nextPage')
                            .remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 
                        $('.posts_area').find('.noMorePosts')
                            .remove(); //Removes current .nextpage 

                        $('#loading').hide();
                        $('.posts_area').append(response);
                    }
                });

            } //End if 

            return false;

        }); //End (window).scroll(function())


    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

i can't really execute your code but you can try to set id_post as attribute for each post you render with js , then next time you get new posts you can know if the post already exists with

```
document.getElementById('id_post')
```

if you get an element you don't re-render  it.
if its empty you can render your post

Comment: i am a starter i don't know what you mean.  i check the code again all are fine but i need to delay or reduce ajax call. load is still process and ajax is trigger another call that why it have same page is load again and again.

Comment: i got it thanks. i add async: false, in ajax call it works. Yae